# Word "None" on line below input

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote a simple program to track household items and output to a text file, with a while loop to have it keep running till "exit" is entered. I get the word "None" on the line below the input line when I haven't written it to do so. Here is my code.

```
HouseHoldItems = open('C:\\_PythonClass\\Assignment03\\HouseHoldItemsAndValue.txt', mode='a')
Items = ''
Value = ''

# while loop to keep program running until user enters "Exit"
while(True):

    # Items is the primary variable, determines if user is entering new household item or wants to end the program
    Items = input(print("Enter an Item (Or type 'Exit' to quit) : "))

    # If statement to determine if user wants to end program
    if(Items.lower() == "exit"):
        break

    # Else statement to write household items to the file, followed by value of items
    else:
        HouseHoldItems.write(Items + ', ')
        Value = input(print("Enter an estimated Value: "))
        HouseHoldItems.write(Value + '\n')

HouseHoldItems.close()
```

Here is a snip of the way the code looks as I input data items. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHOWk.png)

Is it part of the while(true) piece that is making it do this? Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: `help(print)` explains what is wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use the print function when using the input function.
Use:

```
Items = input("Enter an Item (Or type 'Exit' to quit) : ")
```

and:

```
Value = input("Enter an estimated Value: ")
```

While we're at it, in test conditions for while and if statements while your code works as is, it is not considered 'pythonic'. The pythonic way is to not use parentheses. ie

```
While True:
```

and:

```
if Items.lower() == "exit":
```

Comment: Thanks. I totally forgot about that. Still learning! Appreciate the help.

Comment: No problems. Please do get in the habit of marking answers as answer if they do resolve your issue or upvoting answer/comments if they help you in any way